# changing the text box border style in windows form - c#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, border

I have a text box and it is in square form now I want to convert that square into oval shape 
i am using win forms application

can any one tell any idea about this

Comment: I think you will need to override the OnPaint function, of the text box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `SetWindowRgn` API Function to change the shape of a window.
This function - as you can see [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowrgn) - gets three arguments:

1. **Window Handle**: That can be your TextBox Handle and you can get it by `Handle` Property.
2. **A Window RGN**: That you can create it by calling [CreateRoundRectRgn](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/CreateRoundRectRgn.html) (or another RGN creator functions that you can find them [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=rgn&namespace=gdi32))
3. **A Boolean to determine Redraw**: That it is better to be true.

You can subclass from `TextBox` and create a Oval shaped TextBox by using this functions in `OnHandleCreated` Method. The class can be something like this:

```
class OvalTextBox : TextBox
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowRgn(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hRgn, bool bRedraw);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int cx, int cy);

    public OvalTextBox()
    {
        base.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        SetWindowRgn(this.Handle, CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height, 20, 20), true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create ur class inherited by textbox, override OnPaint. Use your custom textbox in winforms.

Comment: set border style to none, and place text box over oval shaped image. It will appear like oval text box visually

Answer (score 1):

Use the [OvalShape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488183.aspx) control and put a textbox inside it.  The textbox should have an an invisible.

Alternatively, create a customcontrol and override OnPaint so that it draws the oval with [graphics.DrawElipse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3fd63x2.aspx).

Comment: do i need add any dll for graphics.drawelipse

Comment: I think I found a better answer for you with OvalShape.  But no, System.Drawing (which I'm sure you already reference) contains the Graphics class.  Override OnPaint in something and it's eventArgs.Graphics.DrawElipse ()

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this using Windows Forms, the only way is to create a new user control and inherit your control from TextBox. Then you must override the OnPaint method and implement your own drawing code.

IF its possible for you to use WPF though, its much easier. If you can make your application a WPF application, then all you need to do is drop a textbox onto your form and then put in a custom template for the shape.